# can i Run KiGG on XP Pro?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, .net-3.5, kigg

I have XP pro edition with .Net 3.5 installed and IIS 5.0 and MVC RC 2
Can i run KiGG on this machine?

Also i have on my hosting server IIS 6 and .Net 3.5 , can it run there or no also?
If no, there is no work around to make it work?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to install an SQL server but yes, you can run KIGG on IIS 5/XP.

ASP.NET MVC is bin-deployable so you should be able to run it on your host also.  I think for a shared host you'll need full trust because it uses some reflection in the code, otherwise you'll get exceptions.

Comment: So this discussion: http://kigg.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=46794 is not right?

Comment: http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/dorony/archive/2007/12/15/using-asp-net-mvc-on-iis-5.aspx